# is normal select statement in oracle database is based on the rownum?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have put on normal select statement in database without sorting any thing,

```
select * from PROFILE;
```

Result is as follows

```
 NAME

=====
a
c
b
```

All i need to know is whether the normal select without sort option is based on the row number or in random fashion.

This doubt raised because of the following select statement.

```
select rownum,name from PROFILE;

NAME ROWNUM
===========
a 1
c 2
b 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Rownum is an artificial column that is in no way a property of the table row.

For example, the queries

```
select rownum, x.* from  (select * from dba_users order by username desc) x;
```

and

```
select rownum, x.* from  (select * from dba_users order by username asc) x;
```

assign different rownums to the resulting rows (but in each case, rownum starts with 1).

Note that `order by` is processed after assigning rownums, so

```
select rownum, x.* from  dba_users x order by username asc;
```

might give you the false impression that a particular row of that table (or view) "has" a rownum.

Without an `order by` clause, a query result can appear in any order, no promises made. A fresh table without deletes probably returns the rows in the order they were inserted, but you shouldn't even rely on that.

Answer (score 1):

The `select` statement, without an `order by` is neither "random" or based on the row number (or row id).  In SQL, tables represent *unordered* sets.  Without an `order by`, the results could be in any order.

In fact, in Oracle, particularly on parallel systems, the results will often come back in different orders for the same query.  This has to do with which underlying thread returns the data first for presentation to the user.

If you want the data in a particular order -- or even just in the same order when you invoke a query more than once -- then use `order by`.